# Deleting entire line based off of string in powershell....and keeping the line below?

Tags: powershell, string

I'm having some issues with powershell.

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

file.txt =

```
string1
a
string2
b
```

I am using the command:

```
Get-Content C:file.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match "string1"}
```

This will erase the remaining lines that do not contain "string1", which is half of what I am trying to accomplish.  Is there a way to have the line below (in this case, where the character "a" is located) stay as well?  I am needing to keep that line regardless of what character is there.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Is it that you want to get the content below "string 1", or always where position "a" is, or do you want to load all the contents of the file but cycle through until you find what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$string = "string1"
$last = ""
Get-Content C:file.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $current = $_
    if (($current -match $string) -or ($last -match $string)) {
        $_
        }
    $last = $current
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Tim.  Thank you for your help! :)